# Data not saved to SQLite DB with multiple tables in Flask using WTForms

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to Save Data to SQLite DB in Flask using WTForms.

I have one main table and three reference tables
these reference tables have 1 field each which is called into my main table using foreignkey relationship.

When I save data using form on webpage. No error appears but data is also not saved to the database tables.

My Models

```
################################################################
##### MODELS CONFIG ###################
################################################################

class dev_inventory(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'inventory'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    host = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    secret = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    type = db.relationship('dev_type', backref='dev_inventory', lazy='dynamic')
    group_name = db.relationship('dev_group', backref='dev_inventory', lazy='dynamic')
    role = db.relationship('dev_role', backref='dev_inventory', lazy='dynamic')

    def __init__(self,name,host,username,password,secret):
        self.name = name
        self.host = host
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.secret = secret

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Host %r>' % self.host


class dev_group(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'groups'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    group = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    host_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('inventory.id'))

    def __init__(self,group):
        self.group = group


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Group %r>' % self.group


class dev_role(db.Model):

        __tablename__ = 'roles'

        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        role = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
        host_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('inventory.id'))

        def __init__(self,role):
            self.role = role


        def __repr__(self):
            return '<Role %r>' % self.role

class dev_type(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'types'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    host_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('inventory.id'))

    def __init__(self,type):
        self.type = type


class manage_users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __init__(self,username,password):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.user
```

Saving data to all other tables working fine except 'dev_inventory'

I am using following form code -

```
class AddDeviceForm(FlaskForm):


    types_choices = [(type.type) for type in dev_type.query.order_by('type') ]
    group_choices = [(group.group) for group in dev_group.query.order_by('group') ]
    role_choices = [(role.role) for role in dev_role.query.order_by('role') ]

    name = StringField('Devive Name')
    host = StringField('Hostname/IP Address')
    username = StringField('Device Username')
    password = StringField('Device Password')
    secret = StringField('Device Secret')
    type = SelectField('Device Type', choices= types_choices)
    group = SelectField('Device Group', choices=group_choices)
    role = SelectField('Device Role', choices=role_choices)
    submit = SubmitField('Add Device')
```

When I fill and save form on web page, it throws no error or print anything on console. though it send a POST request and gives 200 OK but when I check DB, no data is saved in that table.

Here is my code for particular view -

```
@app.route('/add_device', methods=['GET','POST'])
def add_device():
    form = AddDeviceForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        name = form.name.data
        host = form.host.data
        username = form.username.data
        password = form.password.data
        secret = form.secret.data
        type = form.type.data
        group = form.group.data
        role = form.role.data
        device = dev_inventory(name, host, username, password, secret)
        print(device)
        db.session.add(device)
        db.session.add(type)
        db.session.add(group)
        db.session.add(role)
        db.session.commit()
        return "Device Added Successfully"

    return render_template('add_device.html', form=form)
```

I have also tried to save all variables using a single 'db.session.add()' command and then I broke this down further assuming since these are linked to different tables but none of the solution works.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is no necessary to declare an `__init__` method since you are already inheriting from db.Model and db.Model takes care to initialize the properties. I think that is the problem you are struggling on. So, remove the `__init__` methods.

[See Declaring Models](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/#declaring-models)

Additionally, you cannot send as argument the form data (i.e form.name.data) to the db.session.add().

[See Inserting Records](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/queries/#inserting-records)

```
    role = form.role.data
    db.session.add(role) # bad

    device = dev_inventory(name, host, username, password, secret)
    db.session.add(device) # good
```

By another hand, remember the classes declaration have to be as CamelCase and not snake_case.

[Full Documentation of Flask-SQLAlchemy](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/)

Comment: Hi,  Thanks for the answer. I removed the init from all classes but problem remains same

Comment: Have you set the `method='POST'` in the form tag on your HTML template? If you did, you will need to do the validation whether you are doing a POST request since you are using two requests in that view (`method=['GET', 'POST']`)
[See here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#in-the-view) and [Here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/wtforms/#forms-in-templates)

Comment: Quick Update - Seems __init__ is required despite of inheritance.. If I remove it my other other forms which were working earlier stops and I get error on __init__ method.

Comment: What error do you get? I do not think is related to that init method used on your models. Since it is not required unless you will overwrite something on db.Model for that class in particular.

Comment: problem is I am not getting errors... nothing displayed on flask console... just POST request followed by 200 OK

Comment: It seems your form is not being validated as expected. Can you update your question with the template code, please?

Comment: Yeah you are right... issue was with form validation... resolved..